# Persistent Shift - Reduce Conflict in Goldparser

Tags: parsing, shift-reduce-conflict, gold-parser

I'm really stuck with a Shift-Reduce conflict in Goldparser.

I wrote a PHP-like grammar that theoretically should be able to parse the following script:

```
public $Test = null;
protected $bDemo = true;

function Main()
{
}

private function Run()
{
}
```

At the top I want to assign the global variables and after that come the function definitions.

To narrow down the problem I reduced my large grammar to the following lines which can reproduce the error. Obviously this is incomplete. The functions have no parameters, no return value and no statements...

```
"Start Symbol"   = <Script>

! ------------------------------------------------- Sets

{Name} = {Letter} + {Alphanumeric} + [_]

! ------------------------------------------------- Terminals

VarName        = '$'  {Name}*
FuncName       = {Name}*

! ------------------------------------------------- Rules

<Variable>       ::= VarName

<Value>          ::= 'null'
                   | 'true'
                   | 'false'

<Modifier>       ::= 'private'
                   | 'protected'
                   | 'public'

<ModifierOpt>    ::= <Modifier>
                   |

! ---------------

<GlbAssignVar>   ::= <ModifierOpt> <Variable> '=' <Value> ';'

<GlobalList>     ::= <GlobalList> <GlbAssignVar>
                   | <GlbAssignVar>

<GlobalListOpt>  ::= <GlobalList>
                   | 

! ---------------

<FuncDef>        ::= <ModifierOpt> 'function'  FuncName '('  ')' '{'  '}'

<FuncList>       ::= <FuncList> <FuncDef>
                   | <FuncDef>

<FuncListOpt>    ::= <FuncList>
                   |

! ---------------

<Script>         ::=  <GlobalListOpt> <FuncListOpt>
```

When building the LALR Table Goldparser tells me:

*"A Shift-Reduce Conflict was fixed
'private', 'protected', 'public' can follow a completed rule and also be shifted. The conflict was resolved by selecting the 'shift' action over the 'reduce'. Be careful, some parts grammar may not be accessible. It is recommended that you attempt to remove all conflicts."*

But the fix it applies makes that the grammar does not work correctly. In the above example I get a syntax error at `function Main()` where it expects a '`private`', '`protected`' or '`public`' although I declared them as optional.

The error disappears when I remove the `<ModifierOpt>` from either the `<FuncDef>` definition or from the `<GlbAssignVar>` definition.

I have no idea how to solve this. Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that the parser generator is building an `LALR(1)` parser, which means that the parser needs to be able to decide while scanning the input left-to-right (`LR`) whether to reduce an already-completed production or to shift a token which might form part of a not-already-completed production, looking only at the next `(1)` tokens (which is the token which might be shifted).

So, let's suppose we can see only the first token, `private`. Now, there are a couple of possibilities:

1. There is a non-empty `GlobalList`, and the first declaration in it is `private`.
2. The `GlobalList` is empty but the first function declaration in the `FuncList` is `private`.

These correspond to the inputs:

```
private $a = null;

private function a() {}
```

But we can only see the token `private`.

The production we're working on is:

```
<Script>         ::=  <GlobalListOpt> <FuncListOpt>
```

So in the first case, we want to shift `private`, since it will form part of a `GlbAssignVar` which will start a `GlobalList`. In the second case, though, we need to reduce an empty `GlobalListOpt` before shifting the `private`, which will be part of a `FuncDef`. In short, we need to decide whether or not to reduce `GlobalListOpt ::= <empty>` while looking only at the token `private`. And we can't know.

If we could generate an LALR(2) grammar, there would be no problem, because the token following `private` will definitely tell us whether it's a private global or a private function. But since that's not an option with this tool, we need to avoid making the decision until we know.

A simple solution is to get rid of `GlobalListOpt` and fold the optionality into the definition of `Script`:

```
<Script>         ::=  <GlobalList> <FuncListOpt>
                   |  <FuncListOpt>
```

This works because now the parser can always shift the `private`, even though it doesn't know which production will eventually be reduced. (That's the magic of LR parsing: the parser can keep several productions active at the same time; it doesn't need to commit to one or the other until the production is actually reduced.)

Of course, a simpler solution would be to just allow the user to interleave global definitions with functions:

```
<Script>         ::= 
                   | <Script> <FuncDef>
                   | <Script> <GlbAssignVar>
```

which gets rid of `FuncList`, `FuncListOpt`, `GlobalList` and `GlobalListOpt`, but possibly provides the user with what you consider to be too much flexibility.

Comment: You are extremely fast! I recently asked and already got the answer! Thanks! Yes you are right: The error is not were I searched it. It is in the <Script> rule. But your answer is not completely correct, though. I can neither remove FuncList nor GlobalList because the user will want to define more than one function and more than one variable. So what finally works is this: <Script>         ::= <GlobalList> <FuncList>
                   | <FuncList>
                   | <GlobalList>

Comment: @Elmue: Yes, that is more consistent than the first example I provided. I left `FuncListOpt` in my suggestion simply because it was a minimal change. The second example does allow any number of functions and variables. Try it :)