# Is this grammar LR(2) and how can i determine it?

Tags: parsing, grammar, computation-theory, lr-grammar

to determine if my parser is working correctly i need to find a lr(2+) grammar. After a quick research i have found this grammar and i believe that it is lr(2). However, i am not sure how to determine this.

```
Terminals: b, e, o, r, s
NonTerminals: A, B, E, Q, SL
Start: P
Productions:
P -> A
A -> E B SL E | b e
B -> b | o r
E -> e | Ɛ
SL -> s SL | s
```

I would be glad, if someone is able to confirm or deny that this grammar is lr(2) and at best give me a brief explanation on how to determine it by myself.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure it's LR(2), but I don't have an LR(2) parser generator handy to test it, which would be the definitive way to do the test. Of course, you could generate the parser tables by hand. It's not that complicated a grammar, so it shouldn't take you too long.

It's certainly not LR(1), as can be seen from the pair of inputs:

```
b e
b s e
```

The left-most derivations are:

```
P->A->b e
P->E B SL E->B SL E->b SL E->b s E->b s e
```

So at the beginning of the parse, the parser can either shift a `b` in order to follow the first derivation chain or reduce an empty sequence to `E` in order to proceed with the second derivation chain. The second token is needed to choose between these two options, hence a lookahead of at least 2 is required.

As a side note, it should be pretty simple to mine StackOverflow for LR(2) grammars; they come up from time to time in questions. Here's a few I found by searching for `LALR(2)`: (I used a Google search with `site:stackoverflow.com` because SO's own search engine doesn't do well with search patterns which aren't words. Not that Google does it well, but it does do it better.)

[Solving bison conflict over 2nd lookahead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30642967/solving-bison-conflict-over-2nd-lookahead)

[Solving small shift reduce conflict](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60966212/solving-small-shift-reduce-conflict/60972011#60972011)

[Persistent Shift - Reduce Conflict in Goldparser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22702779/persistent-shift-reduce-conflict-in-goldparser)

[How to reduce parser stack or 'unshift' the current token depending on what follows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35431147/how-to-reduce-parser-stack-or-unshift-the-current-token-depending-on-what-foll)

I didn't verify the claims in those questions and answers, and there are other questions which didn't seem to have as clear a result.

The most classic LALR(2) grammar is the grammar for Yacc itself, which is pretty ironic. Here's a simplified version:

```
grammar: %empty | grammar production
production: ID ':' symbols
symbols: %empty | symbols symbol
symbol: ID | QUOTED_LITERAL
```

That simple grammar leaves out actions and the optional semicolon. But it captures the essence of the LALR(2)-ness of the grammar, which is precisely the result of the semicolon being optional. That's not a complaint; the grammar is unambiguous so the semicolon really is redundant and no-one should be forced to type a redundant token :-)